# Как можно передавать данные из одной программы в другую?

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, tcp

Есть программа работающая на одном компе и на другом. Оба компа подсоедeнины к Интернетy.

Как можно передавать данные (strings, ints...) из одной в другую? [python](/questions/tagged/python)

**P.S.** Не шарю в Интернет технологиях к сожалению.

Comment: Самое простое, наверное - поднять веб-сервер на Flask на одном компе и ходить обычным http на этот сервер с другого компа. Но нужно знать ip адрес и чтобы он был виден из интернета.

Comment: @CrazyElf Я уже думал сделать нечто похожее (даже есть код на bottle). Но по-моему это городить огород... Или это правильный путь?

Comment: Ну, совсем правильно делать, наверное, на сокетах, но с веб-сервисом гораздо проще будет отлаживаться, я думаю. http запросы к сервису можно хоть в браузере писать, и на сервисе их просто логировать.

Comment: @CrazyElf Я думал я одинок с такими мыслями.

Comment: @CrazyElf спс !

Comment: Инициировать передачу могут обе стороны? Еще важный момент имеют ли оба хоста реальные IP (обычно - нет и компьютеры в локальной сети закрыты от доступа извне)?

Comment: Ну и еще: ходить обычным http не очень хорошая идея, т.к. во-первых, злоумышленник может подслушать, то что передается, во-вторых, подменить передаваемые данные. Нужно защищенное соединение, например, использовать https. Или установить VPN между этими хостами.

Comment: @RomanKonoval Я просто запаролил. Этого недостаточно?

Comment: Что именно значит 'запаролил'?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108795/discussion-between-roman-konoval-and-victor-vosmottor-thanks-monica).